# Parsing из CDATA html-тегов с помощью PHP

Tags: php, xml, парсер, rss

Добрый день.

```
<description><![CDATA[
 <p><a href="http://pafutos.com/coupon/j24w75f81b1686286c3029547bf01b/"><img src="http://cdn.admitad.com/campaign/images/2016/05/05/469afd8f5cfb41bdaadceb3f5a1def8b.png" width="143" height="59" /></a></p>
 <p><b>Подарок от Valmont!  от <a href="http://pafutos.com/coupon/j24w75f81b1686286c3029547bf01b/">Л&#39;Этуаль</a></b></p>
                    <br />

<p><b>Условия: </b>При покупке продукции Valmont на сумму от 12000 рублей – миниатюра DETO2X 15 мл в подарок!Количество подарков ограничено. 
</p>
                    <br />
<p><b>Срок действия: </b>от 25.04.2017 17:42 <b>до 31.05.2017 23:59</b></p>]]></description>
```

Вот **XML**-файл. Вопрос: какие возможные варианты есть извлечения из CDATA атрибута **'src'** у тега **'img'**?

Comment: Обычной регуляркой не вариант чтоль?

Comment: А в чем проблема с обычными simplexml/xpath и вот этим всем?

Comment: из-за cdata simplexml не видит какие теги внутри description.

Comment: Что значит не видит? Как вы это проверили?

Comment: Это читали http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970602/php-how-to-handle-cdata-with-simplexmlelement?